# Run static website with password auth in cloud

Tags: web, nginx, cloud, serverless

I have a simple one. Static website available after login - easily build and running on nginx.

But it seems to me cumbersome to server static web with small amount of connections (few per day) and spent a hours to set properly and maintain virtual machine during the lifespan of this project.

I use mostly GCP and consider their load balancer, or buckets made for static content, but none of this is able to give you a chance to auth users with passwords.

Do you have any tip for this? Provider is not concern or some kind of serverless with a pay as go will be perfect in my situation.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You may find Firebase useful. They have an [authentication plugin](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/) which seems to do exactly what you need in serverless manner.

Comment: Hi Ernest, nice one! Thanks for the tip. Just for record for others. I made design decision to verify users against username (not mail)  password, which is not how authentication module is made. Rest is very nice with free option included for small projects.